# How to write a property callback for a custom field to use with the Entity module

Tags: entities

I have a custom field with multiple values. I would like it to work with the [Entity module](http://drupal.org/project/entity). I need to create the correct property_callbacks in [hook_field_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7)(). My field schema looks like this:

```
'ref' => array(
  'type' => 'varchar',
  'length' => 32, 
  'not null' => TRUE,
),
'title' => array(
  'type' => 'varchar',
  'length' => 255,
  'not null' => TRUE,
  'default' => '',
),
'description' => array(
  'type' => 'text',
  'not null' => TRUE,
  'size' => 'big',
),
'weight' => array(
  'type' => 'int',
  'unsigned' => TRUE,
  'not null' => TRUE,
  'default' => 0,
),
'status' => array(
  'type' => 'int',
  'unsigned' => TRUE,
  'not null' => TRUE,
  'default' => 1,
),
```

Does anyone know how to actually do this? There is very little documentation around for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of :) ... if its just numbers and strings you can cheat a little. I added some basic integer columns to the User table and wanted EntityAPI and views etc to be aware of them and did the following:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_entity_property_info(). This dpeends on the EntityAPI.
 *
 * This defines the properties/attributes/"fields" of our Entity regardless of
 * whether they are drupal Fields or custom data (in the base table).
 */
function dew_nagging_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $properties = &$info['user']['properties'];
  $properties['dew_survey_count_to_complete'] = array(
    'label' => t('Number of Surveys to Complete'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'description' => 'When a student logs in the system derives how many surveys they must complete. We store this value to make sending the nag email business logic easier.',
    'schema field' => 'dew_survey_count_to_complete',
    'getter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_get',
    'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
  );
  $properties['dew_survey_completed_count'] = array(
    'label' => t('Number of Completed Surveys to Date'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'description' => 'This is a count of the completed surveys completed by a student in real-time. We store this value to make sending the nag email business logic easier.',
    'schema field' => 'dew_survey_completed_count',
    'getter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_get',
    'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
  );
  $properties['dew_surveys_all_completed'] = array(
    'label' => t('Has the student completed all their Surveys?'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'description' => 'This is a boolean indictator (0,1) of whether or not a student has completed their surveys. We store this value to make sending the nag email business logic easier.',
    'schema field' => 'dew_surveys_all_completed',
    'getter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_get',
    'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
  );
  return $info;
}
```

[entity_property_verbatim_set](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.property.inc/function/entity_property_verbatim_set/7) and *_get just pull the field from the database if `$info['schema field']` is defined.

I also had to make the DB changes in my .install file with `db_add_field()` for each database column. I also had to notify EntityAPI of my schema changes to the user table via `hook_schema_alter()`. All these DB schema fields and EntityAPI meta data field defintions must correlate properly.

---

if its more complicated, you do something like found in Ubercart products, you're just returning the item from the given Node and Field.

See http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart%21uc_order%21uc_order.module/function/uc_order_uc_order_get_properties/7.

#### EDIT

Apparently the `entity_metadata_*` functions have been [deprecated](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.property.inc/7) and you should call [entity_property_verbatim_get()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.property.inc/function/entity_property_verbatim_get/7), or `entity_property_verbatim_set()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know if I should be doing the following:

$property['getter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_get';

$property['setter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_set';

unset($property['query callback']);

Comment: I dont know what function you're trying to put that in. the "property getter" and setters go in hook_property_info() or hook_property_info_alter(), hook_field_info() is the Core drupal API hook_property_* is the EntityAPI. I have no other advice at this time.

Comment: I'm using hook_field_info and property_callbacks. I've just seen it in other examples so I guess I should add it. Either way, I've now tested the wrapper and it's saving correctly and getting the data as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simpler example:

```
/**
 * Callback to alter the property info of custom field.
 */
function MYMODULE_property_info_callback(&$info, $entity_type, $field, $instance, $field_type) {
  $name = $field['field_name'];
  $property = &$info[$entity_type]['bundles'][$instance['bundle']]['properties'][$name];

  $property['type'] = 'MYFIELD';
  $property['getter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_get';
  $property['setter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_set';

  unset($property['query callback']);
}
```

This should be called from `property_callbacks` in your `hook_field_info` and it should automatically store your values per each property.