# How to override default cardinality for the field widget?

Tags: 7, entities

I've custom widget which consist multiple input elements in `hook_field_widget_form()` as part of one field (like address field).

The problem is that Drupal complains about:

> this field cannot hold more than @count values

which happens in `field_default_validate()`, when I've multiple input filled, so it doesn't recognise that this is one single field.

I've tried to change my cardinality in every possible place as below, but without success:

```
/** 
 * Implements hook_field_info().
 */ 
function my_address_field_field_info() {
  return [
    'my_address_field' => [
      'label' => t('My Address Field'),
      'settings' => array('cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED),
      'instance_settings' => array('cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED),
      'default_widget' => 'my_address_field_widget',
      'default_formatter' => 'my_address_field_default',
      'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
    ],
  ];    
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_info().
 */
function my_address_field_field_widget_info() {
  return [
    'my_address_field_widget' => [
      'label' => t('Default'),
      'field types' => ['my_address_field'],
      'settings' => array(
        'size' => 60,
        'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
      ),
      'behaviors' => array(
        'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_NONE,
        'default value' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_NONE,
      ),
      'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
    ],
  ];  
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_properties_alter().
 */
function my_address_field_field_widget_properties_alter(&$widget, $context) {
  $widget['cardinality'] = FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function my_address_field_field_formatter_info() {
  return [
    'my_address_field_default' => [
      'label' => t('Default'),
      'field types' => ['my_address_field'],
      'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
 */
function my_address_field_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

  $widget = array();
  $widget['label'] = array(
    '#title' => $instance['label'],
    '#theme' => 'form_element_label',
  );
  $widget['address_line_1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Address line 1'),
  );
  $widget['address_line_2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Address line 2'),
  );
  // more text fields here ...

  return $widget;
}
```

Including defining `hook_field_validate` which I thought it'll override default field validation handler, but this was not the case.

What's the right way of assigning unlimited cardinality for my widget?

Comment: The problem might be in `hook_field_widget_form()` (you might need to go one level deeper in the array you return), could you add your code for that function?

Comment: @Clive I've added my implementation of hook_field_widget_form. Possibly that I'm implementing multi-input field in the wrong way, and it needs to be rewritten as Drupal treats them as separate elements. So as simple workaround I wanted to disable the validation, but it seems it's not possible.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong just by looking at the code. How can I reproduce this? Do you also have a schema? By the way, have you looked at the [multifield module](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the widget form (`hook_field_widget_form`) returns multiple elements at once, by default Drupal recognise them as multiple values of one widget. To override that behaviour, you need to define your properties  in `property_callbacks` hook as part of your [`hook_field_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7) which can return value of your property (in the format documented for your [data type](https://www.drupal.org/node/905580)). See: [Entity property information](https://www.drupal.org/node/1021466).

Then make sure corresponding properties have their Field API schema for a field structure by implementing [`hook_field_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7) in your .install file. Also don't forget to define [`hook_field_is_empty`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_is_empty/7) which tell what constitutes an empty item for a field type.

Here is example code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_schema().
 *
 * This should be placed in .install file.
 */
function MYMODULE_field_schema($field) {
  $column_names = array(
    'addressline1',
    'addressline2',
  );
  $columns = array();
  foreach ($column_names as $column_name) {
    $columns[$column_name] = array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 255,
      'not null' => FALSE,
    );
  }
  return array(
    'columns' => $columns,
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_info() {
  return array(
    'MYFIELD' => array(
      'label' => t('My Field'),
      'description' => t('Provides a custom field.'),
      'settings' => array(),
      'instance_settings' => array(),
      'property_type' => 'MYFIELD',
      'property_callbacks' => array('MYMODULE_property_info_callback'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Callback to alter the property info of custom field.
 */
function MYMODULE_property_info_callback(&$info, $entity_type, $field, $instance, $field_type) {
  $name = $field['field_name'];
  $property = &$info[$entity_type]['bundles'][$instance['bundle']]['properties'][$name];

  $property['type'] = 'MYFIELD';
  $property['getter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_get';
  $property['setter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_set';

  unset($property['query callback']);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_is_empty().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_is_empty($item, $field) {

  // Check if required address components are empty.
  foreach (array('addressline1', 'addressline2') as $required_component) {
    if (empty($item[$required_component])) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

For complete example, check how [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) module implements its field properties, so they work correctly with cardinality settings.

See also: [How to write a property callback for a custom field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/36865/1908)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Field instance cardinality](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_instance_cardinality) module which allows the cardinality of specific instances of fields to be overridden.

> This module allows the cardinality of specific instances of fields to be overridden.
>
> This currently only works with fields that use options widgets (ie select list or checkboxes), and only allows them to be overridden to be single-valued.

Comment: Hello. Could you add excerpt from module page?